# Where is Crystal Reports Page Setup Menu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

This my Report Page :

[image]

I Searched for Page Setup but i can't find it any where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.Right-click on page --> Design -->then Page Setup

Answer (score 1):

Open File in the menu bar --> Page setup

Comment: Yes,it's there but disabled :(

Comment: mmm sorry don't know what you should do.. but if it didn't worked uninstall and reinstall the program